# Laravel : how to do math calculations

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

in the product table I have a selling price column and a purchase price column, how do I get profit from each item and display it in blade.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution 1:

```
// ProductController
public function index() {
  return view('products')->with(['products' => Product::all()]);
}

// products.blade.php
@foreach($products as $product)
Profit: {{ $product->purchase_price - $product->selling_price }}
@endforeach
```

Solution 2

```
// ProductController
public function index() {
  return view('products')->with(['products' => Product::all()]);
}

// Product.php
public function getProfitAttribute(){
  return $this->purchase_price - $this->selling_price;
}
protected $appends = ['profit']; // to append to json

// products.blade.php
@foreach($products as $product)
Profit: {{ $product->profit }}
@endforeach
```

Solution 3 (The best and fastest here)

```
// ProductController
public function index() {
  return view('products')->with(['products' => Product::all(['*', DB::raw('purchase_price - selling_price as profit')])]);
}

// products.blade.php
@foreach($products as $product)
Profit: {{ $product->profit }}
@endforeach
```

Comment: Thank you, I use the third method and succeed.
what if I want to use paginate?

Comment: Solution 2 is nice one to be used.

Comment: The solution 2 is easy to use because you can invoke it any time, however when using it in a loop, a calculation would be made every time you use `$product->profit`. Besides that, if you're returning a json response, it wouldn't be included in the json.

Comment: For paginate you can use `Product::select(['*', DB::raw('purchase_price - selling_price as profit')])->paginate(1)`

Comment: Correction, you can [include the attribute in your json](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-serialization#appending-values-to-json) by adding `protected $appends = ['profit'];` in your `Product.php`. Answer edited.

Answer (score 0):

in your product model:

```
public function getProfitAttribute(){
    return $this->selling_price - $this->purchase_price;
}
```

and get this data `$product->profit` in your blade template.

Answer (score -2):

Make another column into that product table. Then before inserting data to product table make a variable and put the profit there by a simple calculation. Like:
`$profit = $selling_price - $purchase_price;`

then store this to your product table and show the data to your blade file like others.

Comment: Thats True.....